# Is PHP long sleep() inefficient?

Tags: php, cron

I have a code that needs to run in 5 parts, each 10 minutes apart. I know I can run 5 different cron jobs, but the script lends itself to being one script with 10 minute sleep()s at different points.

So I have:

```
set_time_limit(3600);

//code

sleep(600);

//continutes

sleep(600);

//etc
```

Is doing this highly inefficient, or should I find a way to have it split into 5 different cron jobs run 10 minutes apart?

Answer (score 0):

sleep() doesn't consume CPU time but the processes ongoing will consume RAM because the php engine needs to keep running. It shouldn't be a problem if you have a lot of free RAM but I would still suggest splitting it into other crons.

Personally, I've used long sleep (10-20 minutes) in previous web crawlers that I've written in PHP and that ran from my local 4 GB RAM machine with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the task you have, but generally speaking - `it is bad` because it consumes unneeded resources for a long time and has a high risk of being interrupted (by system crash/reboot or external changes to resources which whom script operates).

I'd recommend to use a job queue daemon like RabbitMQ with delaying features. So that after each block you could enqueue a next one in 10 minutes. That will save resources and increase stability